# hping [main] no such device (hping2 windows 8)

Tags: network-programming

When I try to do a simple syn flood attack on localhost, just to get an idea of how hping works, I keep getting this error:

[main] no such device

I don't quite understand what it means or how to fix it. Any help?

Again, I'm using the native win32 hping2.